Signal Separation (constant modulus)
I am trying to separate two source signals, that have constant envelope. The things is that the mixture if forming a Torus, and I am not sure about which algorithm is the most adapted to the situation.
PS: if I plot the first signal, or the second one alone I have a circle (in the complex domain), when I mixed them (addition) I get a Torus:
\begin{align}
S_1 &= A_1 e^{\jmath \theta}\\
S_2 &= A_2 e^{\jmath \theta}
\end{align}

A mathematical formulation would greatly help in understanding the particulars of your problem, e.g. whether the signalsare continuous or discrete in nature, the existence of noise, the characteristics of the mixing channel, etc.

@cjferes I added the equations.

Any information on the mixing? It is just a straightforward sum? Also, do you just have one sample per signal, or do you have multiple samples of each? The equations are not clarifying these aspects, which are crucial to the possible solutions to the signal separation problem

since I cannot comment, it is an instantanious linear mixture (a sum of two signals, s1 and s2)

As far as I can tell, you say the mixture signal is of the form $x=s_1+s_2$, but there are still important details left out. Are the amplitudes $A_1,A_2$ known or unknown? Are the signals varying in time, i.e. $s_i(t)=A_i\exp(2\pi f_i t+\theta_i)$ in general form? If so, do they have equal frequencies $f_i$? Do they hae equal phases $\theta_i$? There is a lot of proposed solutions for signal separation, and methods are very different considering these facts.
